# Maximize the difference of two linear expressions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Given two $1\times N$ complex vectors **h** and **g**. I want to find a $N\times 1$ complex vector **w**(normalized to unit norm $ \Vert w \Vert^2=1$), which maximizes the following expression:
$$w_0=\arg\max_w \left| hw \right|^2-\left| gw \right|^2$$
Because that **w** can represent a direction, I have tried some geometric methods. But what is the geometric meaning of   $\left| hw \right|^2$?

Both of the algebraic and geometric methods are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem: Maximize $|hw|^2 - |gw|^2$ subject to $|w|^2 = 1$

We have $|hw|^2 - |gw|^2 = w^T (h^Th - g^Tg) w$.

This is a standard setup, and is maximized when $w$ is an eigenvector of $h^Th-g^Tg$ with the largest eigenvalue.

---

Here it is as a lagrange multiplier problem for fun:

Let $f(w,\lambda) = |hw|^2 - |gw|^2 - \lambda (|w|^2 - 1)$ and set partial derivatives with respect to $w$ and $\lambda$ to zero:

$\left<w,w\right> = 1$
$2\left<h,w\right>h - 2\left<g,w\right>g - 2 \lambda w = 0$

The second equation is equivalent to:

$(h^T h - g^T g) w = \lambda w$

So $w$ is an eigenvector of $h^Th-g^Tg$.

(Now by the formula in the second line at the top, it's easy to see it must be the one with the largest eigenvalue.)

Comment: This is a quite elegant solution to my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This method is called Lagrange Multipliers.  Start with $F(\vec{w})=|\vec{h}.\vec{w}|^2-|\vec{g}.\vec{w}|^2+\lambda(\vec{w}.\vec{w}-1)$ and differentiate with respect to $w_i$ and $\lambda$.
$$\frac{dF}{dw_i}=2h_i(h.w)-2g_i(g.w)+2\lambda w_i=0$$
That shows that $w$ is a linear combination of $g$ and $h$.  So start again with 
$$w=xh+yg\\
h.h=A,h.g=B,g.g=C\\
\text{Maximize }(Ax+By)^2-(Bx+Cy)^2+\lambda(Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2-1)\\
A(Ax+By)-B(Bx+Cy)+\lambda(2Ax+2By)=0\\
B(Ax+By)-C(Bx+Cy)+\lambda(2Bx+2Cy)=0$$
The last two lines each give $x/y$ as a function of $A,B,C,\lambda$.  Then $\lambda$ must be the only value that gives the same $x/y$ each time.
That gives $x/y$.  Combine that with $Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2=1$ to get a quadratic in $x$.  One root of the quadratic gives a maximum, the other gives a minimum.